# How to make soapclient add xsi:type to request

Tags: php, soap-client

API server requires to specify a type of the passed value

```
<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">vvvvvvvvv</anyType>
```

But `soapclient` generates request without `xsi:type="xsd:string"`

```
<anyType >vvvvvvvvv</anyType>
```

How can I make soapclient to add `xsi:type="xsd:string"` to the request?

Comment: This isn't exactly pretty, but it might help: http://hodgepodgers.com/php-soapclient-and-xsi-types/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is awesome option http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php. I made something like

```
    foreach($values as $v)
    {
        $datafields_set['Values'][] = new SoapVar($v, XSD_STRING, "string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    }
```

works ok